# decodeAudioData from partial data emitted by MediaRecorder

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api, mediarecorder

I got a MediaRecorder which emits audio data every 100 milliseconds:

```
const audioContext = new AudioContext()

export async function getMaxAmplitude(blob: Blob): Promise<number> {
  const data = await audioContext.decodeAudioData(await blob.arrayBuffer())
  const channelData = data.getChannelData(0)

  let max = 0

  // Find the highest amplitude value
  for (let i = 0; i < channelData.length; i++) {
    if (Math.abs(channelData[i]) > max) {
      max = Math.abs(channelData[i])
    }
  }

  return max
}

const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
  audio: {
    echoCancellation: true,
    noiseSuppression: true,
    sampleRate: 44100,
  },
})

const recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, {
  mimeType: 'audio/webm; codecs=opus',
  audioBitsPerSecond: 128000,
})

setRecorder(recorder)

recorder.ondataavailable = async (e) => {
  chunks.current.push(e.data)
  console.log('highest amplitude on current chunk', await getMaxAmplitude(e.data))
}

recorder.onstop = async () => {
  const blob = new Blob(chunks.current, {type: 'audio/webm; codecs=opus'})
  setUrl(URL.createObjectURL(blob))
  console.log('highest amplitude', await getMaxAmplitude(blob))
}

recorder.start(100)
```

But trying to call `decodeAudioData` for the blob emitted by the `ondataavailable` callback will result in a DOMException:

`Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'decodeAudioData' on 'BaseAudioContext': Unable to decode audio data`

I am not sure how to fix that. Funnily enough, if I change the `timeslice` argument in `.start()` from 100 to 1000 the first time `ondataavailable` is called it works, but after that the same exception gets thrown on each callback execution.

I am not sure why this is happening. Has anybody a idea on how to fix that? Using the latest Chrome version.

Comment: decodeAudioData needs the headers, MediaRecorder produces a single file, with a single header. Create multiple MediaRecorder if you want multiple files, but you might be better connecting directly the MediaStream to the AudioContext, depending on what you do.

Comment: I basically want to record an audio file and know what the highest amplitude was in a given timespan, so that I can visualize that to a user